# subsetting a dictionary in jinja2

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

I'd appreciate advice on how to subset a jinja2 dictionary based on a numeric ID. I'd like to use, for example, an iterator (integer 1-7) to select a subset of the following dictionary.

```
{% set p_perturb_dict = {"-50":0.5,"-30":0.3,"-20":0.2, "-10":0.1,"0":1.0, "10":1.10, "20":1.20,"30":1.30,"50":1.50} %}
```

so, for example, using
subset_id=1

I've answered my own question - probably my ignorance but in case this is of use to someone..

I ended up passing in the key (not an ID), for example
PVAL="-50"

then this worked:

```
{%- set p_perturb_dict = dict( {PVAL:p_perturb_dict_all[PVAL]} ) %}
```

and would return a new dictionary with {"-50":0.5" }

Comment: 1 meaning "the first item in the dict"? There are a couple problems with this logic.  Collections are usually 0-ordered, so you would either want `subset_id=0` or you would return the second item.  *However*, dictionaries are not ordered, so you can't select them by index, like it appears you are trying to do.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Hi Thavik - thanks for your reply. Essentially yes, I would like to select from the dictionary with an index - for example the index 1 (or 0) would select the pair  {"-50":0.5" }, and so on.